# Using Azure Data Factory to get data from a REST API

Tags: api, rest, azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

Is it possible to use Azure Data Factory to get data from a REST API and insert it to a Azure database table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Data factory offers a generic [HTTP connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-http-connector) and a 
specific [REST connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/data-factory/connector-rest), allowing you to do retrieve data from HTTP endpoints by using GET or POST methods.

Example: HTTP Linked Service

```
{
    "name": "HttpLinkedService",
    "properties":
    {
        "type": "Http",
        "typeProperties":
        {
            "authenticationType": "Anonymous",
            "url" : "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have done this using Custom .Net Activities.  I had a need to pull data from Salesforce API.  I have a write up on how to do this here: http://eatcodelive.com/2016/02/06/accessing-azure-data-lake-store-from-an-azure-data-factory-custom-net-activity/ it is utilizing the data lake store but you can store the data anywhere.

Also have a look here for an example from microsoft: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-use-custom-activities/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved with Data Factory. Data Factory is useful if you want to run batches on a schedule and have a single place for monitoring and management. There is sample code in our GitHub repo for an http loader to blob here https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory. Then the blob can be consumed for other processing, like putting it into your table.  To do this, you would create a pipeline that contains your custom loader, then an activity with blob as the input dataset and table as the output dataset.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/Samples/HttpDataDownloaderSample

Hi this is a custom data activity that dowloads a file by http request.
You can achieve what you desire making small changes.
Hope it helps.

Comment: The link is dead, use this instead: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-DataFactory/tree/master/SamplesV1/HttpDataDownloaderSample

Answer (score -2):

There is now support for REST as a data source in Azure Data Factory, including pagination

Answer (score -3):

Short answer: Yes :)

Long answer (Tutorial basically): 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-get-started/

Comment: This tutorial uses a azure storage blob as the input data. I want to retrieve data from another source using http calls.

Comment: Indeed, but the principle is exactly the same, just replace blob with REST client and you're green :)